# Difference in allowing both subroutines and functions in an interface in Gfortran and Intel Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

In Intel Fortran, I have following code running successfully (which relates to uniform random number generation)

```
module stats

implicit none
public :: runif
private :: runif_r, runif_r1
interface runif
    module procedure runif_r, runif_r1
end interface 

contains

!get uniform random vector using subroutine
subroutine runif_r(a,b,R) 
implicit none
real, intent(in) :: a,b 
real, intent(out) :: R(:)
call random_number(R)
R = a+(b-a)*R
end subroutine runif_r

!get one uniform random number using function
function runif_r1(a,b) result(r) 
implicit none
real, intent(in) :: a,b 
real r
call random_number(r)
r = a+(b-a)*r
end function runif_r1

end module stats


program test

! use stats
integer, parameter :: n=5
real :: x(n), x1

call runif(1.0, 3.0, x)
print*, x

x1 = runif(1.0, 3.0) 
print*, x1 

end program test
```

While I tried the code in gfortran, it says `Error: In generic interface 'runif' at (1) procedures must be either all SUBROUTINEs or all FUNCTIONs te.f90:41.10:`. I guess different compilers need different requests. How can I remedy this with as few changes as possible!

Comment: Which versions of compilers do you use? Modern features are beinfg added continuously.

Comment: It seems your code is not conforming Fortran.  Fortran 2018 has  _C1514 Within the scope of a generic name, each pair of procedures identified by that name shall both be
 subroutines or both be functions, and..._  I suspect if you tell Intel to apply strict Fortran standard semantic checking you'll get an error.

Comment: I see, I got confused (when referring to thr unspecified modern features) by the possibility to distinguish procedure arguments by being a subroutine or a function. But in that case there is no generic interface for those dummy arguments involved.

Comment: Regarding the ultimate question: "How can I remedy this with as few changes as possible" Well, hard to say. It really depends what you want to ultimately achieve in your real program. But you will have to change the structure or logic somehow.